# Have changed mongodb's password several times. Does it affect previous projects where old password were used?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I have changed mongodb's user's password from database access option. Every time I create a new project, I used to generate a new password for that. Now when I tested some previous projects I discovered some error saying

```
MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed.
    at Connection.onMessage (F:\Practice\MILESTONE-10\genius-car-service-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:202:30)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (F:\Practice\MILESTONE-10\genius-car-service-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:62:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at processIncomingData (F:\Practice\MILESTONE-10\genius-car-service-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:108:16)
    at MessageStream._write (F:\Practice\MILESTONE-10\genius-car-service-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:28:9)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67LxA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Will if the code used the password like

Password: Your Password

as now this code will still try to login with this password which is no longer valid